# how the generator can be compared and add its bool values

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum, zip, tuples

When I iterate the generator, I can use the sum function to compare the values and add them. I don't think bool is additive.Here is the example.

```
A = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
B = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
print(sum(a > b for a, b in zip(A, B)), sum(a < b for a, b in zip(A, B))
```

Comment: What's the problem? This will work. `sum([True, True, False])` is 2.

Comment: yes,the code works.but i want to know how the sum can be used like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boolean is explicitly considered as integer and is a subclass.

To check, we can use `issubclass`:

```
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> Booleans: These represent the truth values False and True [...]
>   Boolean values behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost
>   all contexts, the exception being that when converted to a string, the
>   strings "False" or "True" are returned, respectively

```
sum(a > b for a, b in zip(A, B))
```

Here, `a > b` returns a `True` or `False` depending on whether `a` is greater or smaller than `b` respectively. All the `True`s are infact 1s and `False`s are 0s. `sum()` on them counts number of `True`s.